# Enabling Inline Editing for .Net Template Building Block in SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am working on .Net TBB in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

My component Source looks like this.

```xml
<Content>
  <single>ABCD</single>
</Content>
```

I tried some thing like this.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class SampleTemplate : ITemplate
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Transform as defined by ITemplate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="engine">Templating engine</param>
        /// <param name="package">Package to process</param>
        public void Transform(Engine engine, Package package)
        {
            using (MemoryStream mem= new MemoryStream() )
            {
                Component component = engine.GetObject(package.GetValue("Component.ID")) as Component;
                ItemFields content = new ItemFields(component.Content, component.Schema);


                XhtmlField temp = (XhtmlField)content["single"];

                int i=0;
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

                XmlElement root = xdoc.CreateElement("body");

                XElement xe = null;

                foreach (string val in temp.Values)
                {
                    string j=i.ToString();

                    XmlNode xnode = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, @"tcdl:ComponentField", "tcdlNamespace");
                    XmlAttribute name = xdoc.CreateAttribute("name");
                    XmlAttribute index = xdoc.CreateAttribute("index");
                    name.Value="single"+"["+i+"]";
                    index.Value = "0";
                    xnode.Attributes.Append(name);
                    xnode.Attributes.Append(index);
                    root.AppendChild(xnode);
                    i++;
                }
                package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateHtmlItem(xdoc.InnerText));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here "single" is Multivalued field.

I am getting blank output.

Can any one help how it can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: @ArjenStobbe. I am getting blank screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateHtmlItem(xdoc.InnerText));
```

use

```
package.PushItem("Output", package.CreateHtmlItem(root.OuterXml));
```

Also, I noticed that you are not using field value anywhere. You are iterating over it, but value is not added into the output, not sure if that's what you want